# Bootstrap 4 modal not closing on ESC

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap 4 modal windows. I have setup modal with tabindex="-1" and data-keyboard="true". This should enable ESC button to close the modal.

The problem is, that I programmatically set focus to the first input box in a form. And while cursor is inside this input field, the ESC key is not working, it does not close the modal.

As soon as I click outside the input field, somewhere in modal window, ESC key starts working.

But I would like it to work also, if cursor is in any input field.

What is the issue here?

Comment: We can't diagnose the issue without seeing the code, there could be any number of reasons for this behaviour.

Comment: Here is the link: http://v3.slotenis.si/ Click the Sign Up button

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Since I am listening for ENTER key, I had to include the code for listening to ESC key as well.

```
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        ...; // on ENTER key
    }else if(event.keyCode == 27) {
        ...; // hide modal on ESC
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
```